# Регистронезависимый LOCATE

Tags: php, sql

пытаюсь настроить поиск по базе вот так

```
  $tmpn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE LOCATE(lower('".$sear."'), lower(name))");
```

В переменной $sear - естественно содержится слово - но почему то регистронезависимо он не ищет(( подскажите пожалуйста что у меня не так сей способ я нагуглил на паре форумов но у меня почему то он ищет только регистрозависимо(

Добавлю еще то что на локальной версии сайта зайдя в phpMyadmin кирилица в полях таблиц отображается нормально - но так же база на хостинге выдает кракозябры, http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=34e0c4852c5afbef5344ccfdeb0feadb и на локальном хостинге и на хосте везде в таблицах стоит utf-8_general_ci, у страниц сайта всех поголовно тоже стоит utf-8, но одну разницу только вижу - на моем локальном хосте я залез в Апач в httpd.conf и сменил default charset на utf 8 а вот на веб-хостинге а даже не знаю какой стоит - может дело в этом?

Comment: а для каких слов не работает? для русских? кодировка какая? а для английских работает?

Comment: @BOPOH использую русские слова да для них точно не работает - КОдировка  UTF-8 для английских не знаю но по русским слово Коробка и коробка - точно не срабатывает к примеру

Comment: utf-8 - это кодировка файла же? А при подключении к БД какую указываете? `lower` поддерживает многобайтные кодировки, но по умолчанию используется latin1. Раз у вас это не работает, значит у вас что-то не так с кодировкой при подключении (может быть и для таблицы указана не та, что надо, но здесь не уверен). Попробуйте вместо этого запроса написать, например, `"SELECT lower('".$sear."') AS my_word, lower(name) AS db_word FROM articles LIMIT 1"` и смотрите в каком месте сломалось. При подключении надо указывать `SET NAMES 'utf8'` и таблицы создавать с `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: Да просто афтар наверняка забил в базу или в запрос вместо русской буквы латинскую с таким же начертанием:) Там русская, там латинская. Вот и ищи теперь регистр:)

Comment: Нет у всех таблиц и у базы стоит utf-8_general_ci

Comment: @dantelol, если не сложно, сообщите пожалуйста версии MySQL (локально и на сервере), а также приложите результат выполнения оператора SHOW CREATE TABLE articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в phpMyAdmin данные отображаются некорректно, то вероятнее всего они были добавлены в базу некорректно. Например, вы делали экспорт локальной базы в файл, котоырй был не в UTF-8 кодировке (выгрузку делали до того, как прописали в апаче кодировку по умолчанию) и при импорте кодировки не совпали. Если на локальной базе LOCATE работает как надо - попробуйте перенести данные на хостинг ещё раз так, чтобы они уже отображались корректно.

Comment: по сути да базу создали изначально в utf-8 но импортировали только структуру без данных, потом сменили кодировку в апаче, , после этого попробовали занести новые данные но ничего не получилось - тот же результат, скорее всего действительно данные заносятся не в том формате может задать кодироку на php перед операциями с БД? я вот так попробовал но тоже результата не принесло делал так: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8'); - а далее уже пошло подлючение к БД и тд.

Comment: Ещё нужно указать рабочую кодировку после подключения к БД:
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci');

Comment: это к стати помогло оба ответа дали мне пищу для размышлений но вот идея воткнуть сразу после соединения с БД вот это mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'"); - разрешило проблему полностью Всем спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала попробуйте посмотрите, что происходит с полем lower в запросе

```
SELECT *, lower(name) AS LowerCase FROM articles
```

Так поймете проблема с кодировкой или нет, если регистр нижний то попробуйте построить запрос иначе, ну например как то так

```
SELECT *, lower(name) AS LowerCase FROM articles WHERE
    LOCATE(lower('".$sear."'), LowerCase)
```

Если не помогло, значит смотрите в сторону настройки кодировки базы

Comment: вот так сформулировал запрос    $tmpn = mysql_query("SELECT *, lower(name) AS LowerCase FROM articles WHERE LOCATE(lower('".$sear."'), lower(LowerCase))"); но после этого mysql_num_rows начал выдавать ошибку Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in... что то выдимо в запросе не так пошло(